# Is the docker swarm join token private?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, privacy, terraform, docker-swarm-mode

Is there a risk in publicly (git / blogs) exposing your swarm token; even if your host machines are not publicly accessible via port :2377?

Example: terraform git repo to provision future worker nodes with the worker token contained in the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a theoretical risk, since the [docker swarm mode documentation mentions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-mode/#view-the-join-command-or-update-a-swarm-join-token):

> We recommend that you rotate the join tokens in the following circumstances:
>
> - **If a token was checked-in by accident into a version control system, group chat or accidentally printed to your logs**.
> - If you suspect a node has been compromised.
> - If you wish to guarantee that no new nodes can join the swarm.
>
> Additionally, it is a best practice to implement a regular rotation schedule for any secret including swarm join tokens. We recommend that you rotate your tokens at least every 6 months.